# how to execute collectionView class from different ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

i have a **collectionView** class

```
class LC: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

//in LC

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let VC = segue.destination as? VC2 {
        VC.Rpe = Pass
    }
}
```

**it's working fine** , in **VC2** i have a function when executed it should segue to the next cell in the `collection view`

i'm not sure how or what is the best way to do it (`reload` **VC2** with the next `collection view cell` details?, or run the `collection view` functions programmatically )

**update**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class View2: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var Q_Pic: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Q_que: UILabel!
var SelectedCell: Ques!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Q_Pic.image = UIImage(named: SelectedCell.LIMG)
    Q_que.text = SelectedCell.Q
}

@IBAction func herewego(_ sender: Any) {
    print("when the user press this button it should take him directly to the next cell detail , i don't want the user to go back to collection view and choose the next cell")
}
}
```

**data**

```
let Q_A_TEST_MOH = [
Ques(Q: "Q1? ",LIMG: "1"),
Ques(Q: "Q2? ",LIMG: "2"),
Ques(Q: "Q3?",LIMG: "3"),
Ques(Q: "Q4?",LIMG: "4"),
Ques(Q: "Q5?",LIMG: "5")
]

struct Ques {
var Q : String
var LIMG: String
}
```

**UICollectionViewController**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class test:UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

@IBOutlet var CollectionView: UICollectionView!
var Levelssss: [Ques]!
var ToPass: Ques!
var SelectedCategory: String!
var Level: Int!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    CollectionView.delegate = self
    CollectionView.dataSource = self
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Q_A_TEST_MOH.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "LevelCell2", for: indexPath) as? cell1 {
        let r = Q_A_TEST_MOH[indexPath.item]
        cell.congigureCell(EditLater: r)
        return cell
    }
    return UICollectionViewCell()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    ToPass = Q_A_TEST_MOH[indexPath.item]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "To", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let detalsVC = segue.destination as? View2 {
        detalsVC.SelectedCell = ToPass
    }
}
}
```

**UICollectionViewCell**

```
import UIKit

class cell1: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet var BB: UIButton!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    BB.layer.cornerRadius = 10
}

func congigureCell(EditLater: Ques){
    BB.setImage(UIImage(named: EditLater.LIMG), for: .normal)
}
}
```

Download project from here : [download the project](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=05310788991055115831)

Comment: Hi, I can't get it, what does it mean - `"execute collectionView class from different ViewController"`, you mean execute method from this object?

Comment: If both of your VC is in `UINavigationController` then it would be strange to push one more controller, so if you have data in your second VC and have some method to update UI it should be the better choice to just update it.

Comment: @Andrew, suppose i have 2 cells in a collectionview once i'm in VC2 coming from the first cell, i need to press a button and it' reload VC2 with 2nd cell details.

Comment: how can i configure VC2 to updates with the next cell data.?

Comment: You can pass data for both object, or you can pass the whole array of objects to VC2 and index for object which you want to be shown at first, and then just increment that index)

Comment: @Andrew , can u write a sample code , i'm not able to access [indexPath.item] while i'm in VC2

Comment: You can show me your project? It would be easier to me to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fixed variant: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bc7ktktrbqg9x7t/test%202.zip?dl=0

Logic is simple: pass a whole array of data and index of selected object.

In `VC2` on button click you just increment index and update content of your views.

Now you should just check is index not greater then count of element in array.

Comment: glad it helps you